# SonarQube - help in creating a new language plugin

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I am creating a new plugin for SonarQube which allows developers to perform static code analysis on ESQL code.

Using Maven I can build a shell of a plugin, which produces the JAR file which I can place in the correct folder in order for it to be added to SonarQube.

The next stage is to write the Java classes for the rules, however I am unsure on what and where these look like.  I am using the example from the following GIT repository: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin

Do I simply create a new package with some classes?  And how do I actually rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a rule engine for the ESQL language, this means that you must first write a parser for this language. And only after you completed this stage, you will create a rule engine based on that parser (with visitor classes that navigate through the AST and that create issues under specific circumstances).

You can take a look at how we implemented the Javascript plugin ([see the code of version 1.3](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript/tree/1.3)):

- the "javascript-squid" module is where the parser is written
- the "javascript-checks" module is where the rule engine (based on the parser) is written
- the "sonar-javascript-plugin" module is the actual plugin, which embeds the parser and the rule engine and which provides all the required glue around them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at that today. My manager has also asked me if its possible to have a plugin which runs multiple regex, which are all stored on one file.
Would this be possible has a store of quick and dirty way around it. To begin with I just need to check ESQL statements to ensure it matches up with the clients coding standards